# Cambiar la escala de los ejes para gráficar datos de fichero .CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, matplotlib

estoy realizando cierto análisis y quise realizar esto usando python por aprender un poco más sobre Análisis y visualización de datos con este lenguaje, la cosa va que necesitaba que el gráfico se generara con su respectiva cuadricula y encontre que esto se puede hacer con la función grid():

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema o mejor dicho duda está en que necesito que la escala de la cuadricula en el eje x vaya de 1 en 1, ya que esta representa semanas (1 a 13)

Anexo el código para más información:

```
import pylab as pl
import csv

entrada=open('test.csv')
tabla=[]
for fila in csv.reader(entrada):
    tabla.append(fila)
entrada.close()
x=[]
y=[]
for fila in range(1,len(tabla)):
    x.append(float(tabla[fila][0]))  
    y.append(float(tabla[fila][1])) 
##--------------------------------------------------
entrada2=open('test2.csv')
tabla2=[]
for fila in csv.reader(entrada2):
    tabla2.append(fila)
entrada2.close()
x2=[]
y2=[]
for fila in range(1,len(tabla2)):
    x2.append(float(tabla2[fila][0]))  
    y2.append(float(tabla2[fila][1])) 
#--------------------------------------------------
entrada3=open('test3.csv')
tabla3=[]
for fila in csv.reader(entrada3):
    tabla3.append(fila)
entrada3.close()
x3=[]
y3=[]
for fila in range(1,len(tabla3)):
    x3.append(float(tabla3[fila][0]))  
    y3.append(float(tabla3[fila][1])) 

##líneas-------------------------------------------

pl.plot(x,y,'k',marker='o', color='red',label='Desde 2.5 a 5.0')  
pl.plot(x2,y2,'k:',marker='o', color='m',label='Desde 3 a 5.0')  
pl.plot(x3,y3,'k-.',marker='o', color='lightgreen',label='Desde 4 a 5.0')  
legend = pl.legend(loc='upper right', shadow=True, fontsize='14')
legend.get_frame().set_facecolor('white')
pl.xlabel('Semana')  
pl.ylabel('Partidas')  
pl.savefig('imagen.png')  
pl.grid()
pl.show()
```

En caso de querer que cada punto muestre su coordenada cartesiana, o por lo menos nombrar cada punto y que sus coordenadas aparecieran en un tabla ¿Qué funciones podría usar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que las lineas de la rejilla dependen de las marcas "mayores" del eje, basta con que cambies dichas marcas del <kbd>x</kbd> con `xticks`.

Si sabes de antemano que los valores en el eje van en un rango determinado, de 0 a 13 en tu caso, puedes simplemente hacer:

```
pl.xticks(range(14))
```

si esto no lo sabes de antemano, puedes obtener los valores mínimo y máximo del eje `x` en función de tus datos y crear el rango en base a ellos:

```
import random
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

# Datos aleatorios para emular los obtenidos en tu caso desde csv
x = x2 = x3 = range(1, 14)
y = random.sample(range(140), 13)
y2 = random.sample(range(140), 13)
y3 = random.sample(range(140), 13)

min_x = math.floor(min(map(min, x, x2, x3)))
max_x = math.ceil(max(map(max, x, x2, x3)))
ticks = range(min_x, max_x + 1)

pl.plot(x, y,'k',marker='o', color='red',label='Desde 2.5 a 5.0')  
pl.plot(x2, y2,'k:',marker='o', color='m',label='Desde 3 a 5.0')  
pl.plot(x3, y3,'k-.',marker='o', color='lightgreen',label='Desde 4 a 5.0')
pl.xticks(ticks)  
legend = pl.legend(loc='upper right', shadow=True, fontsize='14')
legend.get_frame().set_facecolor('white')
pl.xlabel('Semana')  
pl.ylabel('Partidas')  
pl.savefig('imagen.png')  
pl.grid()
pl.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias! Disculpa me podrìas recomendar algun sitio o libro para aprender màs sobre el uso de esas librerias?